# C# extention for VS Code by OmniSharp suddenly stopped being able to load my csproj files?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, .net-core, omnisharp

I created a blank dotnet new webapp project in a new folder and the OmniSharp log says:

> [fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
>           Attemped to update project that is not loaded: c:\Users\tttttt\Desktop\rw\rw.csproj

Restarted VS Code multiple times, tried to uninstall and install the C# extension and nothing changes. I don't understand how out of a sudden it stopped working.

Comment: Its unlikely that it happened without any change. Did you update of VS Code? .NET Core SDK? Extenssion? Do old projects still work? If is its unrelated to vscode/omnisharp but is more likely related to you updating .NET Core SDK (newer versions come with new `dotnet new` templates)

Comment: Now that you mentioned, I updated the .NET Core SDK and runtime to 3.0, and relatively at that point it stopped working

Answer (score 0):

> Now that you mentioned, I updated the .NET Core SDK and runtime to 3.0, and relatively at that point it stopped working

Then that may be the issue. With the latest SDK the latest (.NET Core 3.0) tempaltes will be used when creating a new project.

You can however force the tools to use a specific version (on a per folder basis).

Create a `global.json` file in the directory where your projects lie (or one of its parents)

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "2.2.104"
  }
}
```

To use the latest stable .NET Core SDK as default.

All folders below `global.json`'s location will be affected by it. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) on how exactly global.json works.

Alternatively update to a version of VS Code + OmniSharp which support .NET Core 3.0 previews, if you want to use the latest runtime.